Flutter: Display userName and userImageLink in AppBar of ChatPage like WhatsApp
I'm developing a Flutter application where I have a ContactsPage that fetches user profiles from Firestore and allows navigation to a ChatPage for each contact. I want to display the userName and userImageLink in the AppBar of ChatPage just like WhatsApp does.
Here's the relevant code structure:
ContactsPage (contacts_page.dart):
// Imports and class definition...

void navigateToIndividualPage(Contact contact) {
  Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    ChatPage.screenRoute,
    arguments: {
      'name': doc.get('name')?? 'No name',
      'userImageLink': (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?)?['image_link'] ?? '',
      // Other necessary user data
    },
  );
}

ChatPage (chat_page.dart):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String screenRoute = "ChatPage";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final userName = args['name'];
    final userImageLink = args['userImageLink'];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userImageLink),
        ),
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(userName),
            Text(
              'Last seen',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Placeholder for chat UI
      ),
    );
  }
}

When navigating to ChatPage from ContactsPage, I encounter am TypeError on the line final userName = args['name']:

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

This suggests that args['name'] or args['userImageLink'] might be null or missing in some cases.
I've checked that args are correctly passed from ContactsPage using Navigator.pushNamed, and ensured that userName and userImageLink are correctly accessed from args in ChatPage.
I expect the userName and userImageLink obtained from ContactsPage to be displayed in the AppBar of ChatPage, allowing users to see the contact's name and profile image.
Any help on handling null values in args or alternative approaches to achieve this functionality would be appreciated.

Define Route as follows
GoRoute(
      path: 'new_screen',

      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      
        final dataParams = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>;

        final userImageLink = dataParams['userImageLink'];

        return NewScreen(
         userImageLink: userImageLink!,
        );
      },
)

Then in your screen receive it as
//The New screen
class NewScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  //Receive as Params
  final String? userImageLink;

  const NewScreen({
    super.key, 
    this.userImageLink,
  });

  @override
  State<NewScreen> createState() => _NewScreenState();
}

Then you will be able to access your params in this new screen
To Pass them from previous screen use
GoRouter.of(context).push(
        '/new_screen',
        extra: {
          'userImageLink': userImageLink
});


thanks , can you edit my code by this solution
